# ReplaceAll code for meta char?

Tags: android

String str = "How are you today ?-I am fine."

I want to fix this string like that;

**"How are you today? -I am fine."**

I tried this code, but it doesn't work. Could you please help me? Thanks.

```
String asa = "How are you today ?I am fine."
asa= asa.replaceAll(" ?", "?");
```

Comment: You need to escape the `?` character with a backslash: `" \\?"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try this,

```
String asa = "How are you today ?I am fine.";
asa= asa.replaceAll(" \\?", "? ");
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
myString = myString.replaceAll(" \\?", "? ");
```

Let me know if it works or if you need further assistance

Comment: Understood my mistake when looked @Chithra

Answer (score 0):

Try it,

```
String input = "Hello ?I am heisen-berg";
input = input.replaceAll(" \\?", "? ");
```

It will definitely work.